# Website with html and Javascript(fullname, age, amka)

Tags: javascript, html

i don't know what is wrong when i click submit doesn't work..the user gives names surnames ages and amka and when he clicks on the submiτ each entry enters the following list but doesn't work and i dont know why..is a homework, if anyone can help me I appreciated it!!

```
    <script>
        function publishToTable() {
            const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
            const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            const amka = document.getElementById('amka').value;
            const error = document.getElementById('error');
            
            if (fullname && age && amka) {
                const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
                const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
                const tbodyElement = document.createElement('tbody');
                const fullnameEle = document.createElement('td');
                const ageEle = document.createElement('td');
                const amkaEle = document.createElement('td');
                fullnameEle.innerHTML = fullname;
                ageEle.innerHTML = age;
                amkaEle.innerHTML = amka;
                trElement.appendChild(fullnameEle);
                trElement.appendChild(ageEle);
                trElement.appendChild(amkaEle);
                tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);
                tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <script>
        function publishToTable() {
            const fullname = document.getElementById('fullname').value;
            const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            const amka = document.getElementById('amka').value;
            const error = document.getElementById('error');
            
            if (fullname && age && amka) {
                const tableElement = document.getElementById('table');
                const trElement = document.createElement('tr');
                const tbodyElement = document.createElement('tbody');
                const fullnameEle = document.createElement('td');
                const ageEle = document.createElement('td');
                const amkaEle = document.createElement('td');
                fullnameEle.innerHTML = fullname;
                ageEle.innerHTML = age;
                amkaEle.innerHTML = amka;
                trElement.appendChild(fullnameEle);
                trElement.appendChild(ageEle);
                trElement.appendChild(amkaEle);
                tbodyElement.appendChild(trElement);
                tableElement.appendChild(tbodyElement);
            }
        }
    </script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        div.complete {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            padding: 10%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        div.form {
            height: 200px;
        }

        label {
            margin: 20px;
            display: block;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans';
            text-align: right;
        }

        input {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        span {
            color: red;
            position: fixed;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            left: 50%;
            position: fixed;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans';
            
        }

        div#tables {
            height: 300px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans';
            padding: 10px;
        }

        th {
            width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="complete">
        <div class="form">
            <label>Fullname: <input id="fullname" type="text"></label>
            <label>Age: <input id="age" type="age"></label>
            <label>AMKA: <input id="AMKA" type="AMKA"></label>
            <span id="error"></span>
            <button onclick="publishToTable()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tables">
            <table id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name/Surname</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>AMKA</th><br><br><br><br><br>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your AMKA element id to lower case:

```
<input id="amka" type="AMKA">
```